# Как объединить интервалы по заданной длине перекрытия

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, я совсем запутался. Помогите.
Задача следующая: есть интервалы

```
from interval import interval

d = {
    'a': interval([0, 10]),
    'b': interval([5, 40]), 
    'c': interval([30, 50]), 
    'd': interval([55, 70])
}
```

мне нужно получить объединенные группы интервалов по заданному значению минимального перекрытия N

Например если N >= 10, получается

```
{
    interval([0, 10]):['a'], 
    interval([5.0, 50.0]):['b','c'], 
    interval([55.0, 70.0]):['d']
}
```

N >= 5,

```
{
    interval([0, 50]):['a','b','c'], 
    interval([55.0, 70.0]):['d']
}
```

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Я попробовал решить свою же задачу. Код не оптимальный так как я не занимаюсь программированием профессионально. Может кому-нибудь пригодится.

```
def merge_intervals(interval_list,overlap):

    #Дан словарь интервалов
    #data = [(24231, 24894, 1), (26358, 27018, 2), (24231, 24894, 3), ... ]
    #Результат
    #{interval([24231.0, 24894.0]): [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 14, 16], interval([26358.0, 27018.0]): [2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15]}

    def length(interval_):
        """
        Определение длины перекрытия интервала
        """
        try:
            return abs(interval_[0][1] - interval_[0][0])
        except:
            return -1

    # Подготавливаем список тьюполов (конвертируем их в интервалы) и сортируем
    c = list(set([interval[i[0],i[1]]for i in interval_list]))
    c.sort()

    # Объединяем все интервалы в перекрываемые
    merged = interval(c[0])
    for i in c[1:]:
        current = interval(merged[-1])
        # если перекрытие интервалов по заданному условию
        if length(i&current) > overlap:
           # то объединяем интервал из списка с предыдущим
           mer = i | current
           # заменяем предыдущий сохраненный интервал на полученный
           merged = tuple(list(merged)[:-1] + list(interval(mer)))
        else:
            # если условие не выполняется, то просто добавляем к списку
            merged = tuple(list(merged) + list(interval(i)))


    dict_ = {}
    # для каждого из исходных интервалов
    for i in interval_list:
        # для каждого из полученных объединенных интервалов
        for r_i in merged:
            if interval([i[0],i[1]]) in interval(r_i): 
               if interval(r_i) in dict_:
                  dict_[interval(r_i)].append(i[-1])
               else:
                  dict_[interval(r_i)] = []
                  dict_[interval(r_i)].append(i[-1])


    return dict_

if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = [(100,500,1),(50,600,2),(550,700,3),(800,900,4),(850,1000,5)]
    print 'BEFORE', data
    data = merge_intervals(data, 1000)
    print 'AFTER', data
```

Comment: Полезно словами ключевые моменты алгоритма в тексте самого ответа привести (чтобы суть решения, не читая кода уловить, чтобы яснее намерение кода передать (возможные баги отловить, поспособствовать другим реализациям)